# How to calculate standard deviation for estimated marginal means calculated after a GEE model in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation, generalized-estimating-equations

I have an unbalanced longitudinal dataset that looks at the effects of diagnostic tests on costs over time.  First, I run a GEE using geeglm from `geepack` package with interactions to allow for structural breaks. Next, I attempt posthoc analysis using the `emmeans` package to estimate marginal means at each point in time conditional on the interactions. I backtransform to find the response variable.

```
mygeemodel <- geeglm(formula = costs ~ time + variables + 
     break1 + break2 + break1*time+ break2*time, data = mydata, 
     id=ID, family = Gamma(link="log"), corstr = "ar1")

emmformodel <- emmeans(mygeemodel, ~ time | break1 | break2, 
      at = list(time = c(1:100)), options = list(tran = "log"), 
      type = "response")
```

This gives me four lists of emms to compare and each emm at each t is reported with a standard error and a upper and lower confidence interval, as follows:

```
#break1 = 0, break2 = 1:
# time emmean    SE    df    asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
#      1   3.07 0.499 Inf      2.10      4.05
#      2   3.07 0.496 Inf      2.10      4.04
#      3   3.06 0.493 Inf      2.10      4.03
...
```

Could I estimate and interpret a standard deviation for the new means (emms)? Would I look to the underlying population variance of the geeglm output?

Comment: The SD of what, exactly? Note that EMMs are calculated using the regression coefficients; they are not the result of grouping data into subsamples, or similar such operations. And the SEs are calculated from vcov(mygeemodel).

Comment: Thank you @RussLenth, SD of the newly estimated marginal means. I will feed these answers into a MCMC model so I want the scatter of the data underlying the estimated marginal mean.  I tried to make the question more clear above.  Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I guess I have no suggestions. As I said earlier, the data underlying the EMMs are the original data used to fit the model, by way of the model itself. The EMMs are not averages of sets of observations. And also, they are correlated with one another.

Comment: Russ Lenth, what about looking to the underlying variance in the geeglm output? or in the original sample? What are your thoughts on that?